# How to use Windows authentication for SQL Server from a Linux host with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

How can I use Windows authentication for connecting to SQL Server from a SQLAlchemy application that runs on a RHEL (Linux) host?

I could create a dedicated user, with a fixed password, in SQL Server, but in this case, it is required that the user's password be fetched from CyberArk.

Some answers SO suggest using the following connection string:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://*server_name*/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes')
```

However, this doesn't work, since I need to specify the user's credentials (there is no Windows session already present).

Other answers suggest using `pymssql`, however it's outdated in SQLAlchemy doesn't recommend its use. I would rather opt for using `mssql+pyodbc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements, it might be possible, (just) but (imho) very tricky. 
It depends on:
- the sql library writer supporting windows authentication token exchanges
- the sql library writer supporting PAM to get the tokens
- your ability to write a PAM module that will convert the cyberark username/password to retrieve the details.

I'm not familiar with python or those SQL libraries but I would say that even if the authentication approach works on windows, my experience of connecting to SQLServer using other cross-platform libraries is that they tend to lack anything except direct authentication.

You may get lucky as MS adds trusted authentication to SQLServer, but note that they didn't yet.

Even the current recommendation doesn't (I think) meet your requirements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15 
they also link back to deprecated content from there (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) discussing the options and limitations of the available approaches.

I suggest your best approach may be to check whether you can just store a SQL authentication string in CryptoArk and use that.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't MS already added trusted authentication to SQLServer? That's used by most Windows hosts. It's called CyberArk, not CryptoArk. Furthermore, it shouldn't be so difficult to convert a username/password into NTLM authentication, so it's weird it's not implemented. No need for PAM really.

Comment: Sorry for miskeying cyberArk. Windows auth is part of SQLServer when installed on a windows platform, although not (yet) available when installed to a linux one.  Clients need to support windows auth to use it too though. Linux is not usually installed with windows auth, although it is possible, usually using PAM kerberos plugins. To get a linux app to sign into SQL using integrated auth would require that it can use kerberos to respond correctly to the SSPI authentication part of TDS. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/30acd293-86b2-4233-8307-d02ac3b7d55c

Comment: Thank you, @simoncoleman. Actually, many applications have Windows authentication built-in, like the Cntlm proxy etc.